# Changing ASP.NET Login Database

Tags: asp.net, database, authentication

In my test enviroment I created a Login and used the ASP.NET Configuration in Visual Studio. It worked perfectly.
But now after testing I imported an existing database to my sql-server and this database includes existing asp.net login tables(same structure). In my web-application I want to use these imported tables instead of those in my testing database. I already checked the web.config as well as the aspnetreg tool (don't know the exact name :p)

My question: How can I change the database used by my ASP.NET login?

Answer (score 4):

you have to overwrite the default application services connection string to have it use your existing deployed DB

in the web.config connection string section change the default connection string

```
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

to be whatever your connection string is

or if you want to use a different connection string you can change the name of the connection string used in the membership provider settings also in web.config

```
<membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Change the name of the connectionStringName to something else

**EDIT** Role provider code

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Again you will want to change connectionStringName to your connection string.

Comment: There is already the right connectionstring in my web.config. but the ASP.NET configuration tool still tries to connect to the old database. I recognized this after I renamed the old database. The ASP.NET configuration tells me that it could not establish a connection to the database and I need to run aspnet_reqsql tool, but I already tried this to.

Comment: The default web.config settings on the server are somehow overriding yours. add a <clear /> to the connection strings and the membership providers

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I recognized that there is no <membership>-tag in my web.config. How can I generate this? Looks like some kind of strongnamed PublicKeyToken is used. 
I've only got the connection string in my web.config.

Comment: You can copy the code I posted, I copied the code from a working asp.net 3.5 project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I've got a working membership provider. Great!
But, my role provider still isn't working. Would you be so kind and post me this entry, too??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's working now completely. I used the same guid for the roleprovider.

Thanks one more time!